# Degree measure of a missing angle in a polygon

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Claire adds the degree measures of the interior angles of a convex polygon and arrives at a sum of $2017$. She then discovers that she forgot to include one angle. What is the degree measure of the forgotten angle?

so I just kind of guessed and checked like trying to find the total measure of angles of a 16-gon,15,14 and then I got the measure of the 14-gon which was 2160 and subtracted 2017 from it and got the answer 143 which is correct. How do I solve this using modular arithmetic ???? How do I solve this without guess and checking? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That title is not informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of all angles should be a multiple of $180^\circ$, so if the missing angle is $\theta^\circ$ then

$$\begin{align*}
\theta + 2017 &\equiv 0 &&\pmod{180}\\
\theta &\equiv -2017\\
&\equiv 143
\end{align*}$$

(and also the polygon is convex, so $0^\circ < \theta^\circ < 180^\circ$)

Comment: wait how did it suddenly become from theta = -2017 to = 143?

Comment: @QuantumPi $-2017\equiv 143\pmod{180}$ by adding enough multiples of $180$ to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

$2017$ plus the missing angle must add up to a multiple of $180$ (an $n$-gon has angles summing to $180(n-2)$ degrees). Thus
$$2017+x\equiv0\equiv37+x\bmod180$$
so $x=143$, since it lies in $(0,180)$ by the polygon's convexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using modular arithmetic by considering the fact that the sum of the angles in a polygon is always a multiple of 180. Therefore, the sum should be 0 mod 180. Since 2017 is 37 mod 180, we know that the answer would be 180-37 = 143